# Rails Callback - how to stop submit if condition found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When saving a record, I need to stop a submit on a form and throw an error message (I use simple_form).

The condition is that when `annotation.active` is set to true for the record the user wants to save, while an other annotation record exists where `annotation.active` is true with the below fields having the same value as the record the users wants to save, the record should not be saved/updated.

```
annotation.company
annotation.documenttype
```

Am new to ruby / rails (my first app). While using basic rails validations for fields of a record (e.g. presence is true), how to approach above check using rails call-backs or validations?

**UPDATE**

I have been reading the guides on callback, and I think I need to write a method in my "Annotation" model (called on create, save and update) that returns exactly false. Now, I have these questions:

1. what is the difference of before_ and around_ ?
2. is there one callback (before_save or around_save ?), I could use instead of listing several callbacks for each of the methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be resolved using the class method 'validates_uniqueness_of'

more particularly:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :active, scope: [:documenttype, :company]
```

see ruby api doc [1](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the condition in for submit like this:

```
    <script>
      $("form").submit(function (e) {
        if(!annotation.active){ //Your condition to check
           e.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Use this code in your `html.erb` file..

If you need to go with Rails you can use this:

```
submit_tag "Pay", :disabled => !annotation.active
```

or

```
<%= button_to "Submit", "#", :disabled => !annotation.active %>
```

Comment: that would be jquery. I want to use rails / ruby.

Comment: Hi Gokul, wondering if you may help me doing it with rails validations as per validations guide.